# Checking if an xy position is within a rectangular bounds

Tags: javascript

This is pretty straightforward, but is there a better way to do this?

```
function isWithinBounds(obj, pos) {
    var oXmin, oXmax, oYmin, oYmax;
    if (obj.startPos.x < obj.endPos.x) {
        oXmin = obj.startPos.x;
        oXmax = obj.endPos.x;
    }
    else {
        oXmin = obj.endPos.x;
        oXmax = obj.startPos.x
    }

    if (obj.startPos.y < obj.endPos.y) {
        oYmin = obj.startPos.y;
        oYmax = obj.endPos.y;
    }
    else {
        oYmin = obj.endPos.y;
        oYmax = obj.startPos.y;
    }

    return (pos.x > oXmin && pos.x < oXmax && pos.y > oYmin && pos.y < oYmax);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is. You can use [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to determine which is the smaller end and the larger end. This way, you avoid the `if` statements.

```
function isWithinBounds(obj, pos) {
    var oXmin = Math.min(obj.startPos.x, obj.endPos.x);
    var oXmax = Math.max(obj.startPos.x, obj.endPos.x);
    var oYmin = Math.min(obj.startPos.y, obj.endPos.y);
    var oYmax = Math.max(obj.startPos.y, obj.endPos.y);
    return ( oXmin < pos.x && pos.x < oXmax && oYmin < pos.y && pos.y < oYmax);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with someone like this, which reduces the heart of the logic to a single declarative line (the one with the return statement):

```
function isWithinBounds(obj, pos) {
  var xs = [obj.startPos.x, obj.endPos.x].sort(),
      ys = [obj.startPos.y, obj.endPos.y].sort();
  return contains(xs, pos.x) && contains(ys, pos.y);
  function contains(arr, x) { return x > arr[0] && x < arr[1] }
}
```

Or if you want to avoid all repetition:

```
function isWithinBounds(obj, pos) {
  var xs = boundsOf('x'), ys = boundsOf('y');
  return contains(xs, pos.x) && contains(ys, pos.y);
  function contains(arr, x) { return x > arr[0] && x < arr[1] }
  function boundsOf(prop) { return [obj.startPos[prop], obj.endPos[prop]].sort() }
}
```

Though personally I prefer the first variation.

Answer (score 1):

Have not checked to see if this function is faster:

```
function check(a, b, p) {
    var f = b - a, g = b - p;
    return (Math.abs(f) >= Math.abs(g)) && (Math.sign(f) === Math.sign(g));
}
```

To use the function do the following:

```
function isWithinBounds(obj, pos) {
    return check(obj.startPos.x, obj.endPos.x, pos.x) &&
           check(obj.startPos.y, obj.endPos.y, pos.y);
}
```

---

**How Does It Work?**

Since your rectangle is always upright, we can focus on just looking at one dimension at a time. The hard part is the fact that you only have two points on the rectangle and we do not know what is the top/right or bottom/left which is why you first figure out which one is greater. So, this attempt was to see if I could still figure out if was in between without actually checking which was top or bottom.

First we take `a` to be the start and `b` to be the end. Then we define `f` to be the difference between the two `f = b - a`. Also, let the value that we want to know if is between `a` and `b` be `p`. Then we can define `g` to be the difference between `b` and `p`,  `g = b - p`.

So, we can represent all of the different cases `a`, `b`, and `p` can be placed.

```
|----a----p----b----|
|----b----p----a----|
|----b----a----p----|
|----p----a----b----|
|----a----b----p----|
|----p----b----a----|
```

Now let us also place the `f` and `g` values next to the different combinations.

```
                        f   g
|----a----p----b----|  +#  +# (|g| < |f|) true
|----b----p----a----|  -#  -# (|g| < |f|) true
|----b----a----p----|  -#  -# (|g| > |f|) false
|----p----a----b----|  +#  +# (|g| > |f|) false
|----a----b----p----|  +#  -# (|g| ? |f|) false
|----p----b----a----|  -#  +# (|g| ? |f|) false
```

As you can see, when `|g|` is smaller than `|f|` and the signs of `g` and `f` are the same then `p` is between `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

**• Function signature :**

since you are checking if a point is within a rectangle, your function signature is too vague, it would be better called `isPointInRect`. obviously if it is meant to be a method shared by circles, polygons, ... the name is fine.
But as your question is written i'd change the signature and add a comment to precise the strict inclusion, and have arguments ordered like in english :

```
// Returns if the point is strictly within the rect.
function isPointInRect(pt, rect) {
```

**• DRY / cache your property access :**

You should notice at the first glance that you are using again and again the same properties, and writing the same things : it hinders both readability and performances.

You should at least cache startPos, endPos, ptX, ptY :

```
var startPos = rect.startPos, endPos, rect.endPos;
var ptX = pt.x, ptY = pt.y;
```

And you might also want to cache `startPos.x/y` and `endPos.x/y`, but see the next point.

**• Do not repeat computations :**

It is most likely that there will be far more point test than rect change : but as you wrote the code, for each point testing you'll have to re-order the rect points.
I suggest that your `Rect` class already keeps your points or coordinates in the right order. So either have two `topLeft`, `downRight` points or `left`,`right`, `top`, `down` properties (or, the classics : `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`).

**• exit the sooner you can  :**

*Assuming that most point test will fail*, you'd better write you last conditional the other way around to exit sooner:

```
return ! ( ptX <= rect.left || ... || ... || ... ) ;
```

So your function might now read :

```
// Returns if the point is strictly within the rect.
function isPointInRect(pt, rect) {
    var ptX = pt.x, ptY = pt.y;
    return ! ( ptX <= rect.left || ptX >= rect.right 
                ||  ptY <= rect.top || ptY >= rect.down ) ;
}
```

(personaly i prefer the `x/y/width/height` version of the `Rect`, especially since `Rect` might extends `Point` :

```
// Returns if the point is strictly within the rect.
function isPointInRect(pt, rect) {
    var dx = pt.x-rect.x, dy = pt.y-rect.y;
    return ! ( dx <= 0 || dx >= rect.width 
                ||  dy <= 0 || dy >= rect.height ) ;
}
```

)